# There is a holomorphic and bijective function of $\mathbb {D}$ in $\mathbb{D}\setminus(0,1]$?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, complex-numbers

There is a holomorphic and bijective function of $\mathbb{D}$ in $\mathbb{D}\setminus(0,1]$? where $\mathbb{D}$ denotes the open unit disk in the complex plane.

Idea: I really need to prove that there is a holomorphic and bijective function of $R={\{z\in\mathbb{C}: Re(z)>0 , Im(z)>0}\}$ in $\mathbb{D}\setminus(0,1]$ But just find a function with such properties of $\mathbb{D}$ in $\mathbb{D}\setminus(0,1]$, and then make the composition with the transformation of cayley and the function $f(z)=z^2$.

Thanks for the help!!

Comment: Are you sure you want to keep $0$ ?

Comment: Do you mean $\mathbb{D}\setminus[0,1)$? If so you can appeal to the Riemann Mapping Theorem.

Comment: @nicomezi Yes, exactly.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown I need $\mathbb{D}\setminus(0,1]$

Comment: Consider $z \in D \backslash [0,1) \longmapsto \sqrt{-i\log{-z}} \in R$ (note that $D \backslash (0,1]$ is not open.

Comment: @Mindlack Is $\sqrt{-ilog(-z)}$?

Comment: $\mathbb{D}\setminus(0,1]$ is not open, so the Open Mapping Theorem dooms you.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Can you explain me a little. Thank you.

Comment: Holomorphic functions map open subsets of $\mathbb{C}$ to open subsets of $\mathbb{C}$. So there is no holomorphic map defined on $D$ with image exactly $D \backslash (0,1]$.

Comment: Are $D$ and $D \backslash (0,1]$ homeomorpic?  That is, are $D$ and $D \cup \{1\}$ homeomorphic?

Comment: By clicking the "edit" button, you can correct your question and its title by changing $\mathbb D \setminus (0,1]$ to $\mathbb D \setminus [0,1)$.

Answer (score 5):

No, there isn't a homeomorphism, let alone a biholomorphism.

Suppose there exists a **homeomorphism** $f\colon \mathbb{D}\backslash (0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{D}$. We may remove $0$ and $f(0)$ ans still get a homeomorphism $f\colon \mathbb{D}\backslash [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{D}\backslash \{f(0)\}$.

Since $\mathbb{D}\backslash [0,1]$ is a simply connected open subset of the plane and, on the other hand, $\mathbb{D}\backslash \{f(0)\}$ is not simply connected, we have a contradiction.

**Handwavy heuristic approach:**

Let $p=f(0)\in \mathbb{D}$  and take an arbitrary small disc $D$ with $p\in D\subset \mathbb{D}$. Since $f$ is a homeomorphism, $f^{-1}(\bar D)$ must contain $0$ and its boundary must be a closed simple curve enclosing $p$ totally inside $\mathbb{D}\backslash (0,1]$ which is impossible.

**Added:**
To be precise, a holomorphic bijective map is a biholomorphism as a consequence of the [Open Mapping Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_mapping_theorem_(complex_analysis))

**Added 2:** Just a courious fact. It follows directly from the Open Mapping Theorem that any holomorphic map $f\colon \mathbb{D} \rightarrow \mathbb{D}\backslash (0,1]$ whose image contains $0$ is constant.

Comment: You’re implicitly using that every bijective holomorphic map is already biholomorphic, which relies on the open mapping theorem. Maybe you should add that, make it explicit.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out

Comment: Yes, the fact that a holomorphic bijection is a biholomorphism requires the Open Mapping Theorem. But the fact that a holomorphhic homeomorphism is a biholomorphism is more elementary, and in particular does not require OMT.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich The OP asked for a  holomorphic bijection.

Comment: Ah, right. Then in fact all you need is the OMT for non-constant holoomorphic functions, which again is much more elementary than the OMT from topology...